# How to reverse a URL in VB?

Tags: vb.net, string, reverse

I have a string called "homepage" like so:

```
Dim homepage As String
homepage = TextBox1.Text
```

As an example, homepage equals "http://www.example.com". All I need to do is reverse the URL to "com.example" without "http://www".
I have tried the following code:

```
Dim i As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(homepage, (InStr(homepage, ".")))
Label1.Text = i
```

That code should select all letters after the last fullstop, but it doesn't. Can someone please help me? I'll provide more info if needed.
The URL will not always start with http://www, but it does start with http://. a URL doesn't always have www.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Right` to get *n* characters at the end of the string. But the value you are passing as your argument from `InStr` returns the position from the start of the string.

Try subtracting the value returned by `InStr` from the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Will the URL always start with "http://www."?

```
Dim reversedPartUrl As String = String.Join(".", homepage.Replace("http://www.", "").Split("."c).Reverse)
```

Or if there's a chance there will be something like /index.html on the end,

```
Dim homepage As Uri
homepage = New Uri("http://www.example.com/index.html")
Dim s As String = String.Join(".", homepage.Host.Split("."c).Reverse)
```

Comment: No it doesn't always start with http://www. because some people have subdomains. However, it does always start with http://

Comment: You should be able to modify the line of code I gave to suit your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim homepage As String
        homepage = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"

        'Reverse the URL
        Dim revURL = StrReverse(homepage)

        Dim theURL
        theURL = Left(revURL, InStr(InStr(revURL, ".") + 1, revURL, ".") - 1)

        ' Reverse it back
        homepage = StrReverse(theURL)
        Console.WriteLine(homepage)
        Console.ReadKey()
```